# Jquery:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having above error though this Jquery function is working fine.

Html:

```
<div id="context">
            <h2>Digital Library</h2>
            <a href="#" id="first" class="open">What is Digital Library?</a>
            <p id="one" style="display:none;">A digital library is a special library with a focused collection of digital objects that can include text, visual material, audio material, video material, stored as electronic media formats (as opposed to print, microform, or other media), along with means for organizing, storing, and retrieving the files and media contained in the library collection.</p><br>
            <a href="#" id="second" class="open">How to search for specific ebook?</a>
            <p id="two" style="display:none;">To search an ebook, you just need to search for your desire ebook in below text boxes.When you click on search, a table with relevant results will show up.</p><br>
            <a href="#" id="third" class="open">How to download ebook?</a>
            <p id="three" style="display:none;">To download an ebook you just need to click on download link, in the table results</p>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.open', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('#context');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

But because of this there is a link that is not opening.

Html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ebook">
                <li><a href="ebook.php">Ebooks</a></li>
                <li><a href="research.php">Research Journal</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've already checked link spelling and other aspects but can't find any solution. Please help me! Thank you

Comment: It is because `target` is invalid. There is no such element.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); will stop default behavior of anchor tag that is redirect to new location, also where is open class on html ?

Comment: You're asking about a handler that handles clicks elements with the class `open`, but you haven't shown us any elements with that class.

Comment: There is such element. Check it now @Sverri M. Olsen

Comment: I've added html which contains open class. Check it now @A.T.

Comment: Check it now @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @AishaSalman But there is no `#context` attribute on the clicked element, which means that `target` is invalid. You probably need to use `var target=$(this).parents("#context")`.

Comment: I did what you recommend but still no use my friend @SverriM.Olsen

Answer (score 2):

That tells you that there is no element matching the selector in `target`. Since there's no matching element, `offset` returns `undefined`; when you try to do `undefined.anything`, you get an error.

So you need to look at `target` and figure out why it's not a valid selector for the element you're trying to get. You can do that with the debugger built into your browser by setting a breakpoint on the `scrollTop: $(target).offset().top` line and hovering the cursor over the `target` variable.

Now that you've quoted the HTML, we can see that the elements with the class `open` don't have a `#context` attribute (which would be a very, very strange name to choose — and extremely awkward to write, if it's even possible — in any case).

If you added `data-context="one"` and such:

```
<a href="#" id="first" data-context="one" class="open">What is Digital Library?</a>
```

..and then used `data-context`:

```
var target = this.getAttribute("data-context");
```

...and showed the element:

```
$(target).show();
```

...it would work:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-context');
  $(target).show();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div id="context">
  <h2>Digital Library</h2>
  <a href="#" id="first" data-context="one" class="open">What is Digital Library?</a>
  <p id="one" style="display:none;">A digital library is a special library with a focused collection of digital objects that can include text, visual material, audio material, video material, stored as electronic media formats (as opposed to print, microform, or other media), along with
    means for organizing, storing, and retrieving the files and media contained in the library collection.</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="second" data-context="two" class="open">How to search for specific ebook?</a>
  <p id="two" style="display:none;">To search an ebook, you just need to search for your desire ebook in below text boxes.When you click on search, a table with relevant results will show up.</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="third" data-context="three" class="open">How to download ebook?</a>
  <p id="three" style="display:none;">To download an ebook you just need to click on download link, in the table results</p>
</div>
<div style="height: 30em"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**That said**, it's much more complicated than necessary as the links and the paragraphs they're showing are right next to each other. The links dont' need `id`s at all (they never did, unless you're using them for something you haven't shown) and neither do the paragraphs (unless, again, you're using them for something you haven't shown). Instead, just use `$(this).next()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).next();
  target.show();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).next();
  target.show();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div id="context">
  <h2>Digital Library</h2>
  <a href="#" class="open">What is Digital Library?</a>
  <p id="one" style="display:none;">A digital library is a special library with a focused collection of digital objects that can include text, visual material, audio material, video material, stored as electronic media formats (as opposed to print, microform, or other media), along with
    means for organizing, storing, and retrieving the files and media contained in the library collection.</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="open">How to search for specific ebook?</a>
  <p id="two" style="display:none;">To search an ebook, you just need to search for your desire ebook in below text boxes.When you click on search, a table with relevant results will show up.</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="open">How to download ebook?</a>
  <p id="three" style="display:none;">To download an ebook you just need to click on download link, in the table results</p>
</div>
<div style="height: 30em"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check my html now @T.J. Crowder

Comment: this jquery function is working absolutely fine but the thing is my navbar link is not opening.

Comment: @AishaSalman: I have no idea what navbar you're talking about. The above answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is an error, the function don't work fine.
2. You get the attribute `#context` but I think you need attribute `context` (without #).
3. The HTML you shared is not related with the Javascript

To solve it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.open', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('context'); // see here
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Because the error is produced because `$(target)` is not finding any element, so there is not `offset()` method and there is not `top` property.

Comment: I've removed # before context but still the link is not opening @Marcos Perez Gude

Comment: @AishaSalman: That's because your elements didn't have a `context` attribute on them at all. (They also *shouldn't*, it's an invalid attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of this code,

 event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('#context');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

use this,

```
event.preventDefault();
$("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('context')).offset().top 
        }, 2000);
```